# Need to find maximum level where child is present in a parent child relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, algorithm

Here is the JSON object, so if I look at below object it has children till level 3 and object at level 3 has no children's.

So what is the efficient way to find out?

```
 {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Economic Segment",
    "maxLevel": 10,
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Revenue",
            "maxLevel": 9,
            "parentId": 2,
            "children": [
               {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "R Child",
                "maxLevel": 8,
                "parentId": 7,
                "children": [
                    {
                      "id": 12,
                      "name": "R Child",
                      "maxLevel": 8,
                      "parentId": 7,
                      "children": []
                    }

                  ]
               } 
             ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Expenditure",
            "maxLevel": 9,
            "parentId": 2,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Asset",
            "maxLevel": 9,
            "parentId": 2,
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}}
```

Comment: loop through and check whether that object has any children... there is no other way

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Berto99, but the problem is there can be n number of child and to loop and find out is not very efficient I guess. I am looking for a way to add something in the object (or MySQL table) which helps to find it out easily.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't image from where you get this json, and without ordering it by something, there is no other way (maybe if you post the code which generate this json, i can help you)